# How to reload lazy collections with hibernate after transaction is closed

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions, lazy-loading

Let's say I got two Java POJOs: University and Student. "University" includes a list of Students.

That collection is marked for lazy loading in the hibernate mapping file. 
So if I receive a "University"-object from hibernate, I can't access the students list after the transaction is closed.

That is a problem for me, because in some (not every!) case I need to access this list. This would be no problem, if i would do all the work in the database layer of my application. But as you can imagine: that layer is only responsible for CRUD tasks.
Changes are made in the business layer. So if the business layer receives that object, the transaction is already closed.

What is best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is [Open Session View](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView). Also you can initialize the child entities by calling getters/ iterating through child collection before closing the session.